# Restrict Background Data

Tags: background-data

When I enable Restrict Background Data the pop up says that some apps and services will not work unless the device is connected to WiFi.
How can I know which specific apps and services?

Answer (score 1):

The apps that requires constant internet connection and cannot be run without it. But they will notify you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried lots of apps but the only one of them complained about background data: Google play store. It doesn't want to work without background data.

All apps I ever used work fine with BG data restricted.

I recommend not use the restriction for downloaders, SoundCloud (if you are listening to the music, it will stop buffering after you minimize the app or turn off the screen); some messengers and email clients may stop receiving messages while phone is sleeping.